# Testing for false in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to test whether a `check_box` in my rails app is checked.

Here's the code in my model:

```
attr_accessor :post_to_facebook

before_save :to_facebook?

def to_facebook?
 if self.post_to_facebook
   // do stuff
 end
end
```

And in the view:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.check_box :post_to_facebook, :checked => 'checked' %><%= f.label :post_to_facebook %>
</div>
```

Checked or not, Rails is always evaluating `to_facebook` as true. For example, this is what was posted in the log: `"post_to_facebook"=>"0"`, but it still evaluated as true. Can anyone spot what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, only `false` and `nil` are evaluated as `false`. That means `"0"` (or even `0`) is "truthy". What you can do is :

```
def to_facebook?
  if self.post_to_facebook.eql? 'checked'
    # your stuff
  end
end
```